# Blue Lesson 23# can I use for-loop here?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I was trying to detect every token in the sentence t1 to the sensitive word in the string sen[], but seems it does not work well with the for loop

```
package IntelliJ.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter next sentence: ");
        String s1 = kbReader.next();

        StringTokenizer t1 = new StringTokenizer(s1, " ");
        String sen[] = {"Hermes", "bridge", "Muddy", "River", "assault", "offensive"};
        boolean Reject = false;


        while (t1.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String m = t1.nextToken();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                if (m.equalsIgnoreCase(sen[i])) {
                    Reject = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Reject)
            System.out.println(">>>REJECTED");
        else
            System.out.println("OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: "but seems it does not work well with the for loop" you need to give a specific description of the problem.

Comment: You're using `next()` and then try to tokenize on a space. You should be using `nextLine()` to capture the entire sentence.

Comment: Try `kbReader.nextLine()` instead of `kbReader.next()`

Comment: @GBlodgett It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @Eritrean Thanks a lot.